# Извлечение метатэга description регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
preg_match('/(<meta name="description" content="(.*)" >)/i',$content, $patterns);
```

Есть такая регулярка. Но она не устраивает. Потому что если при разборе страницы **name="description"** стоит в конце метатега, то оно пропускает. Скажите, как поставить условие? Хотелось бы условие поставить самой регуляркой, а не определять, нашло ли оно такой. Если нет, то пробовать в конце найти это **name="description"**. Потому как могут быть и другие символы.

Так же условие должно быть, чтобы это обязательно было **description** - и не попадались другие метатеги.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/<meta(?=[^>]* name *= *"?description"?) [^>]*?(?<= )content *= *"([^"]*)"[^>]*>/i
```

Результат придет в первой группе.
Ограничение по регексу: вопреки стандарту HTML content должен быть заключен в кавычки.